# How to solve "The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full reload!)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Building a react app to learn and found that webpack would help me with HMR.

But when I change something in a component(JSX) it does not update and gives me the following:

> The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full
>   reload!)
>
> log.js:26 Ignored an update to unaccepted module ./src/App.js ->
>   ./src/index.js -> 0

Code:

Webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  // devServer: {
  //   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
  //   port: 3000,
  //   publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
  //   hotOnly: true,
  //   historyApiFallback: true
  // },
  // plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './public/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
}),
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hotOnly: true
}
};
```

Json:

```
{
  "name": "reactpluralsight",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "PluralSightTutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "MrCode",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

babel:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Hello } from "./The basics/FirstComponent"
import { Hook } from './The basics/FirstHook'
// import { HookC } from './The basics/FirstHookChallange'

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
       <Hello/>
       <Hook/>
       {/* <HookC/> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The somewhat irritating part is that this worked yesterday but today for some reason it stopped. I am working in the three JSX components:

```
Hello Hook HookC
```

But when I change something in them i always get the same log message in the browser.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: 
dont know if this matters but I am using npm and gitbash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I figured this out.

My original webpackconfig looked fairly different then in the question but I could not get it working so I tried  a few other attempts.

The big problem turned out to be the devserver.hotOnly which according to docs:

> Enables Hot Module Replacement (see devServer.hot) without page
>   refresh as fallback in case of build failures.

This turned out to be misleading since when you remove the hotonly prop and have a config like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"],  plugins: ["transform-class-properties"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

The HMR works.

related info found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/877)